# How to pass categoryId from one ViewModel to another in Knockoutjs - Error categoryId undefined

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two Bootstrap dropdowns, when I select a category in the first one, the second one should be populated according to the categoryId of the first one. I'm trying to pass categoryId from reportCategoryViewModel to reportTypeViewModel using the subscribe function but it doesn't work as expected, I get the error categoryId undefined.

```
var shouter = new ko.subscribable();
function reportCategoryViewModel() {
...
self.selectedReportCategoryName = ko.observable();
self.selectReportCategory = function (reportCategoryList) {
    self.selectedReportCategoryName(reportCategoryList.reportCategoryName);
    var categoryId = reportCategoryList.reportCategoryId;
```

This code works fine, I tested it with an alert, when I select a category, the alert shows the correct categoryId:

```
    alert("reportCategoryViewModel - categoryId " + categoryId);

    self.reportCategoryId.subscribe(function (categoryId) {
        shouter.notifySubscribers(categoryId, "categoryIdForSelectingTypes");
    });
};

function reportTypeViewModel() {
...
self.selectedCategoryId = ko.observable();
self.reportTypes = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedReportType = ko.observable();
self.selectReportType = function (reportTypeList) {
    self.selectedReportType(reportTypeList.reportTypeName);
};
```

I'm  not sur if I pass the categoryId correctly inside the shouter here below:

```
shouter.subscribe(function (categoryId) {
    self.selectedCategoryId(categoryId);
}, self, "categoryIdForSelectingTypes");
```

The error occurs because selft.selectedCategoryId() here below doesn't contain a valid categoryId:

```
var uriReportType = 'api/reporttypes/' + self.selectedCategoryId();
var reportTypeArray = [];
$.getJSON(uriReportType)
    .done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            reportTypeArray.push(item);
            self.reportTypes(reportTypeArray);
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
var masterViewModel = (function () {
    this.reportCategoryViewModel = new reportCategoryViewModel();
    this.reportTypeViewModel = new reportTypeViewModel();
})();

ko.applyBindings(masterViewModel);
});
```

[Here is the JsFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/ZotNet/z7yb7nfg/)

Error: GET http://localhost:49758/api/reporttypes/undefined 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Please edit your code to be a [mcve]: add some view code, make the JS code syntactically correct and so that it's a repro. Stub out the data retrieval bit. Etc. (Preferably create a runnable snippet.)

Comment: @Jeroen I edited the question and added the JsFiddle code.

Comment: @ZotNet - your fiddle is not loading KO

Comment: @brianlmerritt thank you! I added KO to External Resources now and also some hardcoded data to self.reportCategories = ko.observableArray([...])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### KO Postbox example

I have an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0uz3yo5g/3/ with ko.postbox.

You start by loading ko.postbox, then when you create your observable, you set up a publish channel, e.g.

```
self.reportCategoryId = ko.observable().publishOn('reportCategoryID');
```

I have commented out the shouter code - it's best not to mess with the global space and stick to either vm to vm comms (via postbox) or centrally (as per my github example)

All you need to receive the events is a ko.postbox.subscribe, e.g.

```
ko.postbox.subscribe('reportCategoryID', function(categoryId) {
    self.selectedCategoryId(categoryId);
    alert("categoryId VM2" + categoryId);
}, self, "categoryIdForSelectingTypes");
```

### Central ServiceProvider with ViewModel

I tend to use a central service provider (singleton) to hold data and provide functions to manipulate the data or get new via api etc.

For example

```
const ko = require('knockout');
const CentralState = {
    signIn : componentName => signIn(componentName),
    signedInComponents : ko.observableArray([]),
};
const signIn = (componentName) => {
    if (CentralState.signedInComponents().indexOf(componentName) < 0) {
        CentralState.signedInComponents.push(componentName);
    }
};
module.exports = CentralState;
```

You can see it set up here https://github.com/brianlmerritt/knockout-babel-browserify-gulp with two service providers (one for api, one for state) including Gulp and Babel conversion so you can use new Javascript.

Either way you simply subscribe to the central service provider observable or to the ko.postbox 'channel' to get updates when the other view model changes affect you.

Comment: Thank you! but it's a little bit complicated to implement this in my case because I'm starting to learn KO... Can you please help?

Comment: Done, but please do have a look at the github example, as it includes both custom components and central service providers, plus supports ES6 so you can stop all of the self=this pain and use => functions

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have seen the Github example but it's a lot of information and I don't understand how to apply it in my code... The intellisense doesn't work at this line : self.selectedCategoryId = ko.observable(reportCategoryViewModel.categoryId); When I type the dot after reportCategoryViewModel to get the categoryId, there is no categoryId in the different options. This line : alert("categoryId VM2" + categoryId); renders an undefined categoryId when the page loads but when I select a category nothing happen.

Comment: No worries, but postbox now updates the other view model(s) when the observable changes. Just set the desired category at the start, and process the category changes as needed.

Comment: The category should be selected by the user, there is no default category and when I select a category, the parameter is not accessible in the second ViewModel... Should I also use the code you described below "Central ServiceProvider with ViewModel" ?

Comment: No - just put the self.reportCategoryId etc etc in the viewModel which owns the data-bind to the html form, and the ko.postbox.subscribe etc in any other viewModel and either set another observable there or trigger the code to process the change. Sorry, your code is not clear in terms of what it does, and I can't rewrite it for you.  Do you understand what postbox is for, and how it is used?

Comment: Yes I understand the postbox ...  But I forgot to use this line : ko.postbox.publish("reportCategoryID", categoryId); It's working fine now. Thank you!